# Ubuntu. Не может перейти на сервер

Tags: ubuntu, сервер

Я работаю с Ubuntu, мне необходимо перейти на сервер, по полученному адресу, но при попытки подключится высвечивается вот такая ошибка. Хотелось бы понять, что не так и как её устранить.
Вот сама ошибка:

```
File "/home/vboxuser/lab3/backend/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```

[image: 122 строка из сообщения об ошибке]

Comment: Во-первых, код должен быть текстом, а не скриншотом, и представлять собой [mcve], а не огрызок. Во-вторых, текст ошибки намекает, что никакого сервера на самом деле нет

Comment: @andreymal, ОП на столько преисполнился, что точно знает в каком именно месте ошибка. А скрин - потому что код на столько гениальный, что каждый захочет его перепечатать себе руками. Скрин не помеха.